# tcp server working fine but udp server showing error in php

Tags: php, tcp, udp, port

Here is the php code

```
    <?php

$hostname = "127.0.0.1";
$portno = "5060";

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Socket create error\n");
socket_bind($sock, $hostname, $portno) or die("Socket bind error\n");
socket_listen($sock, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");

while(1)
{
    echo "socket connection started\n";
    $accept = socket_accept($sock) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
    while($recv = socket_read($accept, 24000))
    {
        $sent = socket_write($sock, $recv, strlen($recv));
        echo $recv;
    }
    socket_close($accept);
    echo "socket connection done\n";
}

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

it works as TCP server.In order to convert that into udp server i modified a line in creating server

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) or die("Socket create error\n");
```

But it's showing error

```
Could not set up socket listener
```

while trying to do a listen.

Comment: which error? Check that port is not already busy with a nestat -na

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `socket_listen` can be used with UDP.  From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-listen.php):

> socket_listen() is applicable only to sockets of type SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_SEQPACKET.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need socket_listen().

Use `socket_recvfrom()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recvfrom.php